# The way accept software from packages.ros.org

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found first step of ROS installation is to setup your sources.list, so we can install or update from **apt-get** command, but I am wondering what's the kind of this repository.
I found [Repositories/Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Canonical_Partner_Repositories). I think the ROS one may be **extras repository** or **partner repositories.** which one is right. thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268451/the-way-accept-software-from-packages.ros.org/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2017-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Canonical, the makers of Ubuntu, would consider the ROS package repository an "Extras" repository. As described on that page,

> There are times when you might want to add extra repositories to your system's software sources (that is, in addition to the repositories provided by Canonical).

That's exactly what the ROS repository is. It's an extra repository that is not provided by Canonical.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0